# Focus an element on main view while showing ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I Have been looking around this for a while now and could not find solution;

When you create ProgressDialog, the Main View is turned to grey and loses focus,What I want to do is to keep an element from the Main View focused (lets say Admob) and keep it usable while the ProgressDialog is shown

UPDATE : CODE !

```
View mainview = LayoutInflater.from(MainAct).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        View adView = mainview.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainAct);
        mProgress.setMessage("Downloading...");
        mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgress.show();
        adView.requestFocus();
```

it seems like using reaquestFocus doesn't work and is only intended for form elements, not bringing elements on TOP

UPDATE 2:
[image: SAMPLE]

Comment: Why not use a `ProgressBar` in your layout, hide the rest, except your `AdMob` until it finishes processing, then hide the `ProgressBar` and show your actual layout instead?

Comment: @SiddharthLele it is better to show ads on transition pages, Temporary Dialog, than permanently showing them somewhere in the main view, this way the user will not be annoyed and will increase click rates

Comment: Sorry. But I am clearly not getting your point. Also, Dialog's, whether they are `ProgressDialogs` or otherwise, don't work that way.

Comment: @SiddharthLele take MXPlayer for example, you only see ads when you pause the video, otherwise you see nothing, I want to do something similar, only show ads when downloading, since I have limited choices with progressdialog; I can only create the ad in the main View, And set it visible when downloading and give it focus while the progressdialog is shown

Comment: I am still thinking, if you need the visibility to remain focused and usable on the activity where you are downloading data, while allowing the user to interact with your AdMob Ad, embedding a ProgressBar (Horizontal) will be a much better alternative.

Comment: If there is a way to give the Element focus while progressdialog is shown I would Use it, If you are 100% sure that I cant implement that, I will do what you suggested

Comment: No mate. Using a `ProgressDialog` will **always** hide the layout below it. Using a `ProgressBar` will let you show the progress while still showing the Admob. Let me post some sample code to get you started. I don't guarantee that this is the solution you are looking for. I still am not a 100% sure of what you need done. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
                style="@style/Spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp" >
            </ProgressBar>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Loading...."
                android:textColor="#F1F1F1"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#f1f1f1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code above is for a layout that is used almost exclusively in own of my apps. What I do while loading the data is quite simple.

Look at how the ProgressBar is defined in the XML. While still loading data, I change the `LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress` to `VISIBLE` which effectively hides the `ListView` below it because of the attributes set to it. After I am done loading the data, I change the visibility of the `LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress` to `GONE`. A point to note here is, the Admob XML right at the bottom of the XML, is always visible to the user and *can be interacted with* anytime before or after the data is loading / done loading.

If you need to show this XML in the form of a `Dialog`, you can always do so by attaching a Theme to this activity.

Hope some of this helps in your endeavour.

**UPDATE**

Check these tutorials. These are a few I could find with a quick search for showing a `Horizontal ProgressBar`. You are using a `ProgressDialog`.

1. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-batterymanager-and-progressbar-two-for-one-tutorial/703
2. http://theandroid.in/example-of-progressbar-in-android/

And finally, use this [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+activity+like+a+dialog&oq=android+activity+like+a+&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i30j0i8i30l2.77.3368.0.4423.24.16.0.7.7.0.246.2322.0j14j2.16.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.Kx0NpoUjm6U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.bmk&fp=bd45917f4d5afbf9&biw=1440&bih=775) to see a few examples of making an activity look like a dialog.

This should help you achieve what your screenshot suggests.

Comment: I have updated the Question with a picture, as you can see the ad is on greyscale and unusable,now regarding your solution, I would rather show new window with progress and ad than altering the main view and dismiss it later, any ideas ?